# Reading data from Firebase Array-Like

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a model in Firebase, who is saved like this:

[image: my model at firebase]

Im fetching the data in my componentDidMount like this:

```
fetchMatches = async () => {
   const { firebaseApp, auth, pool } = this.props;


     await firebaseApp.database()
       .ref(`/pools/${pool.key}/users/${auth.uid}/`)
       .once('value')
       .then(snapshot =>{
         this.setState({matches:snapshot.val()})
       })  
 }
```

The problem is, that my state, becomes an object: Not an Array, not a list.

How can I read this data, in a proper way that I can filter it based on an atribute.

When I try to do

```
let matches = this.state.matches;
    for (let index = 0; index < matches.length; index++) {
      const element = matches[index];
      console.log(element);
    }
```

It not works.

When I try to use a this.state.matches.map() they say that is not a function. And it really isnt as on my debugger this.state.matches is an OBJECT.

What Im doing wrong here?

Comment: Don't use sequential numeric ids in distributed data. Use push ids or other. Avoid arrays. Try snapshot.forEach() instead on your data. If you need to, push it to an array there. But ideally filter your data with queries.

Answer (score 0):

When you are fetching data with the once function it returns an object of that specific ref, in that case, it will return this ${auth.uid} data as an object.
So you might want to change your ref a little bit to: ref(`/pools/${pool.key}/users/${auth.uid}/matches`),
then to loop through the matches children, according to the firebase documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events

```
await firebaseApp.database()
    .ref(`/pools/${pool.key}/users/${auth.uid}/matches`)
    .once('value')
    .then(snapshot =>{
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
       var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
       var childData = childSnapshot.val();
       // ...
    });
})
```

Comment: Got it T.Sagiv. Nice idea. But, ok, I make a push on every childData on an array. And then, how can I do a this.setState(matches:arrayOfChildData), if i cant acess those data outside the forEach loop ?

Comment: If i understand you correctly you can declare a variable before the forEach function and then in the forEach function you can push the data to that array and after the forEach funtion finish you can set the state with the array of childs

Comment: Yes. I try to do this. But I got a compiler error: 

fetchMatches = async () => {
    const { firebaseApp, auth, pool } = this.props;
    let values = [];
    await firebaseApp.database()
      .ref(`/pools/${pool.key}/users/${auth.uid}/matches`)
      .once('value')
      .then(snapshot => {

        snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
          const childKey = childSnapshot.key;
          const childData = childSnapshot.val();
          values.push(childData);
          
        }
        this.setState({matches: values});
        );

Comment: You need to declare the values array after the once function like that: fetchMatches = async () => { const { firebaseApp, auth, pool } = this.props; await firebaseApp.database() .ref(/pools/${pool.key}/users/${auth.uid}/matches) .once('value') .then(snapshot => { let values = []; snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => { const childKey = childSnapshot.key; const childData = childSnapshot.val(); values.push(childData); } this.setState({matches: values}); );